# Input[type="search"] not working on IE9 and below

Tags: html, css

`input[type="search"]` not working on IE9 and below. Please can you give me idea about it? It will be very thankful. you can see the screenshot:

[image]

```css
.search-form .row input[type="search"] {
    color:#9fa0a0;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0;
    line-height:25px;
    border:none;
    background:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    padding:8px 5px 7px 11px;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
}
```

Comment: I think most browsers will interpret an input with an unsupported type as a standard text input

Comment: Don't support IE9. Problem solved :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because `<input type="search"/>` is itself not supported by IE so it falls back to text field.Check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_form_input_types.asp).

You can use this trick to get similar effect in case of fallback

```
.search-form .row input[type="search"],
.search-form .row input {
    color:#9fa0a0;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:0;
    line-height:25px;
    border:none;
    background:none;
    -webkit-appearance:none;
    padding:8px 5px 7px 11px;
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    float:left;
}
```

PS : make sure you don't have any other `input` fields under `.search-form .row` as otherwise this will affect those too. So I would suggest using an *Id* selector for this field